# How do I check if element is visible or not from an ngIf router.url check using Jasmine in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a div that I want to display only if the current route is a particular page, otherwise hide it all other times and I am trying to write a Jasmine unit test for this.

HTML markup:

```
<div class="header" *ngIf="router.url ='/home'">
```

Jasmine unit test:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
    let component: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
    let el: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        el = fixture.debugElement;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should display div when on the home page', () => {
        expect(el.query(By.css('.header')).nativeElement.style.visibility).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should hide div when not on home page', () => {
        expect(el.query(By.css('.header')).nativeElement.style.visibility).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

NOTE: the first page when the app loads the route will be /home.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-write your router URL value at every test. because it is a read-only property, consider using `Object.defineProperty` :

```
it('should display div when on the home page', () => {
  Object.defineProperty(component.router, 'url', { writable: true, value: '/home'});
  expect(el.query(By.css('.header')).nativeElement.style.visibility).toBe(true);
});

it('should hide div when not on home page', () => {
  Object.defineProperty(component.router, 'url', { writable: true, value: '/not-home'});
  expect(el.query(By.css('.header')).nativeElement.style.visibility).toBe(false);
});
```

Comment: thanks!  This gets me in the right direction, but my tests are failing because it thinks the visibility property is ''.  I am not sure how angular handles ngIf when going to styles.

Comment: after changing the first unit test to check the contents of the .header class, it worked.  But the second unit test fails because it thinks we are still on the /home route as defined in the markup.  I would assume I need to actually trigger a route change and then test?

Comment: No, you would need to call `fixture.detectChanges()`, which is made to update the view.